# Ubuntu- BIOVIA GUI installation

Tags: gui

Hi I am trying to install a .bin software from terminal (Ubuntu16)
http://accelrys.com/products/collaborative-science/biovia-discovery-studio/visualization-download.php

On running installation it says: 
Initializing InstallShield Wizard........
          Launching InstallShield Wizard........
The installer is unable to run in graphical mode. Try running the installer with the -console or -silent flag.

I tried looking for libxp6 but couldn't find it. Anyway around to install it other than using -console and -silent flag.

With -console it does install correctly but on startup the program crash/close itself automaticaly after 5 secs.

error: Aborted (core dumped)

thanks in advance.

Comment: After installing the program using the `-console` flag, try launching the software from  a terminal window so any error messages are viewable in the terminal. Do you see any errors or messages there after the program crashes/closes?

Comment: Hi Nick : it says   Aborted(core dumped)

Comment: The error message that you received tells you that the Windows installer for a program is unable to run. In Ubuntu it is possible to run some Windows programs in Wine. For example, DS ActiveX Control is a Windows program that depends on ActiveX.

Comment: Thanks Karel; seems have to go for a dual boot, it's a long shot to get activeX with Wine